# Installing JavaFX in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm trying to install JavaFX to my Eclipse (version Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)) using [these instructions](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html), but I'm getting following error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed:
    e(fx)clipse - IDE 2.0.0.201506111511 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201506111511)

Missing requirement:
    org.eclipse.fx.ide.l10n 2.0.0.201506111511 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.l10n 2.0.0.201506111511) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.equinox.common 3.7.0' but it could not be found

Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: e(fx)clipse - IDE 2.0.0.201506111511 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201506111511)
    To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.l10n.feature.feature.group [2.0.0.201506111511]

Cannot satisfy dependency:<br>
    From: e(fx)clipse - IDE - l10n support 2.0.0.201506111511 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.l10n.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201506111511)
    To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.l10n [2.0.0.201506111511]
```

I'm using JRE 8, Compiler compliance level set to 1.8, if that helps in any way. What do I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Those instructions say Eclipse 4.5 (Mars) is required and they mean it, Eclipse 4.4.2 won't do.

In detail the error message is telling you that version 3.7.0 of the `org.eclipse.equinox.common` plugin is required - this is only in Eclipse 4.5.

The [Releases](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/releases.html) page covers earlier releases for older versions of Eclipse. However the release for Eclipse Mars is version 2.0 (up from 1.2) so you probably want to switch to Mars to get the latest code.